# What is the word for this (facial) expression?

Tags: word-request

When the loved one gently puts his/her head on your shoulder, there is smile on your face with the thought, I am always here for you. This expression is like a smile, and then there is caring thought going on. When you do it, it's not a proper smile, but a half smile, but gentle. Like when a kid comes to you and puts his head on your shoulder, you'll have this expression. It's a smile not to show to them, or anyone, it's just you do it as if you mind is programed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is one specific word for this exact situation. However, the first thing that popped into my mind was:

- **a warm smile**

Interestingly enough, in its definition for *warm*, [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/warm_1) says:

> **warm** (*adj.*) kind and friendly in a way that makes other people feel comfortable : 
>   *a warm smile*

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/warm) also says:

> **warm** (*adj*.) intimate; close: as, *warm friends*

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/warm?q=warm_1) says:

> **warm** (*adj.*) friendly and loving:
>   *They're a very warm family*.
>   *He has a lovely warm smile*.

Again, I wouldn't say that *warm* is the definitive correct answer, but it is one possible expression you could use.